# SQL Server - Display the username in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL Server 2012 database that 4 developers use, lets call them, user1, user2, user3, user4.

I want to create a column in one of the tables lets call the column User_Input, this column needs to show the username of the developer who insert any data, is this possible? For example if user2 inserted a new record, the column User_Input should display user2.

Please let me know if SQL Server does not support that, and if there is any other solution cause I searched the @@ functions for SQL Server and non of them seems to get the username.

Comment: I assume they're connecting using different credentials, and not all connected using a single SQL Server user account?  If so, you can use [System_User](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)

Comment: That is true, each individual has his/her own account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SYSTEM_USER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) function will return the login name of the user.

You can test it out with this statement:
    SELECT SYSTEM_USER

The [MSDN documentation for SYSTEM_USER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) states:

> You can use the SYSTEM_USER function with DEFAULT constraints in the
>   CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements. You can also use it as any
>   standard function.

Here is a quick example of how to create a table with DEFAULT constraint that inserts the `SYSTEM_USER` into the User_Input column.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
   ID int, 
   Value varchar(30), 
   User_Input varchar(200) DEFAULT SYSTEM_USER
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
```

You can add this to inserts/updates as needed.

`CURRENT_USER` provides the schema, not the login associated with the transaction.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is correct, We need to use the System_User function.